# Transaction ID has invalid size

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm trying to get information regarding a transaction from testnet, so I'm sending a JSON request to monero-wallet-rpc:

```
{"id":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"get_transfer_by_txid","params":"0e2a8c486d5a57fe8d48ba3e7ca07ad1735eb1f3026e3d1021ca7ee3238fe7db"}
```

But I'm receiving:

> `{"error":{"code":-8,"message":"Transaction ID has invalid size: "},"id":"0","jsonrpc":"2.0"}`

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you passed it an empty (non existent) txid. It should have 64 hex chars, not 0.

params is a dictionary containing a "txid" field, but you set it to a string, so parsing does not find the txid it's expecting where it's supposed to be. Fix this.